# A Wheel of fortune game in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, slice

In my game, the word is displayed as underscores at first, so for the word house, the output would be: _ _ _ _
I can't figure out how to replace these underscores with the correct letters that the user answered as they guess the letters in the word. For example, if the user guessed the letter 'o', then the program would print "Correct! Here is the word so far: _ o _ _ "
This is the snippet of code that generates the amount of underscores printed out on the screen:

```
random_value = random.randrange(len(WORDS))
chosen_word = WORDS[random_value]
blanks = (len(chosen_word) * "_ ")
```

Now all i need to do is figure out how to replace those underscores with the users input, one letter at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [93]: chosen_word = 'house'

In [94]: state = "_"*len(chosen_word)

In [95]: guess = 'o'

In [96]: new_state = [(chosen if chosen == guess else blank) 
                      for chosen, blank in zip(chosen_word, state)]

In [97]: ' '.join(new_state)
Out[97]: '_ o _ _ _'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing something more like:

```
In [126]: blank = ['_'] * len(chosen_word)

In [127]: blank
Out[127]: ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']

In [128]: ' '.join(blank)
Out[128]: '_ _ _ _ _'
```

so that `blank` is now an array of blank letters. Then when a user makes a correct guess, you could replace the corresponding index in `blank` with the correct letter, and print it out using the `.join()` method above

Answer (score 0):

```
guessed_letters = 'qxz'
for letter in chosen_word:
    if letter in guessed_letters:
        print letter
    else:
        print '_'
```

Go over the letters of the secret word. For each letter, print it if it has already been guessed. If it has not, print a `_` instead.

You could shorten it to

```
guessed_letters = 'qxz'
for letter in chosen_word:
    print letter if letter in guessed_letters else '_'
```

or even

```
print ' '.join(letter if letter in guessed_letters else '_' for letter in chosen_word)
```